# Can the Oracle DRCP connection pool and a middle tier connection pool run simultaneously?

Tags: oracle, connection-pooling, oracle12c

We have several web applications using my-batis as a connection pool on the web server.  We are using the Oracle 12c database.  Now we are adding a new application X which uses individual connections for every request and is very inefficient.  We would like to enable the Oracle DRCP connection pool and have application X use it without affecting the previously existing apps that have a connection pool.  Our DBA informed me that it looks like all the applications will have to use the Oracle DRCP connection pool if it is enabled, meaning we will have to reconfigure the connection method in all of our applications for this application X.

Does anyone know if this is the case, or can you have the Oracle DRCP connection pool running without affecting our middle tier connection pools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle DRCP does not interfere with any other connections methods you are currently using, it only adds another option to connect to the DRCP connection pool.

This was verified when the DBA decided to give it a try and turn on the DRCP connection pool in our Oracle database.  We were able to connect to the new DRCP connection pool with our new application X and our other applications continued to work without any modification necessary.